Facet plot removing NA categories ggplot2
I have a geom_col graph where I want to split out longer x-axis labels and combine labels for bars. I have tried doing this a few ways but each contains bars with NA values that I want to be removed.
I am using the following code to create the graphs:
library(ggh4x)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

dftp=data.frame(so=c("All", "GBMSM","Heterosexual men White","Heterosexual men other ethnicities","Heterosexual and bisexual women White", "Heterosexual and bisexual women other ethnicities"),
                V4=c(5000, 2000, 400,900,350,1100),
                so1=c("", "","Heterosexual men","Heterosexual men","Heterosexual and bisexual women","Heterosexual and bisexual women"),
                so2=c("All", "GBMSM","White","Other ethnicities","White","Other ethnicities"))

ggplot(data=dftp)+
  geom_col(aes(x=
                 forcats::fct_relabel(so2,
                                      stringr::str_wrap,
                                      width = 18)
               ,
               y=V4),width = 0.6)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .06)),
                     labels=scales::comma,
                     limits=c(0,max(dftp$V4)))+
  facet_nested(~ so1 + so2) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.text = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=9),
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=12, colour="black", hjust=0.5),
        legend.position="none",
        axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text = element_text(colour="black"),
        plot.title.position="plot",
        plot.subtitle=element_text(size=12, face="bold"))+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, subtitle = "Number of people tested")

ggplot(data=dftp)+
  geom_col(aes(x=
                 forcats::fct_relabel(so2,
                                      stringr::str_wrap,
                                      width = 18)
               ,
               y=V4),width = 0.6)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .06)),
                     labels=scales::comma,
                     limits=c(0,max(dftp$V4)))+
  facet_wrap(~ so1, switch = "x") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.text = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=9),
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=12, colour="black", hjust=0.5),
        legend.position="none",
        axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text = element_text(colour="black"),
        plot.title.position="plot",
        plot.subtitle=element_text(size=12, face="bold"))+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, subtitle = "Number of people tested")

Both ggplot alternatives are displaying empty bars which I need to remove (see screenshots showing categories highlighted yellow I want to remove).


